# Error while creating thumbnailes only for some images using php

Tags: php, image, thumbnails

I got an error while uploading multiple images using php7.2-fpm and apache2 server in the backend, it's just few images among a lot of images, so i would like to know if my code has any thing wrong with it, or what's the real problem for this.
This is the code responsible for errors :

```
function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) {

        $info = getimagesize($source_url);

        if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')
              $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);

        else if ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif')
              $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);

        else if ($info['mime'] == 'image/png')
              $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);

        imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
        return $destination_url;
    }

    //Create Thumb Image
    function create_thumb_image($target_folder ='',$thumb_folder = '', $thumb_width = '',$thumb_height = '') {  
     //folder path setup
         $target_path = $target_folder;
         $thumb_path = $thumb_folder;  

         $thumbnail = $thumb_path;
         $upload_image = $target_path;

            list($width,$height) = getimagesize($upload_image);
            $thumb_create = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width,$thumb_height);
            switch($file_ext) {
                case 'jpg':
                    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload_image);
                    break;
                case 'jpeg':
                    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload_image);
                    break;
                case 'png':
                    $source = imagecreatefrompng($upload_image);
                    break;
                case 'gif':
                    $source = imagecreatefromgif($upload_image);
                     break;
                default:
                    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload_image);
            }
       imagecopyresized($thumb_create, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $width,$height);
            switch($file_ext){
                case 'jpg' || 'jpeg':
                    imagejpeg($thumb_create,$thumbnail,80);
                    break;
                case 'png':
                    imagepng($thumb_create,$thumbnail,80);
                    break;
                case 'gif':
                    imagegif($thumb_create,$thumbnail,80);
                     break;
                default:
                    imagejpeg($thumb_create,$thumbnail,80);
            }
    }
```

and here is a hint of errors i got in error.log file

> fcm.php on line 157\nPHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable:
>   file_ext in fcm.php on line 160\nPHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined
>   variable: file_ext fcm.php on line 137\nPHP message: PHP Notice: 
>   Undefined variable: file_ext

etc, and want to mention again that this happens for only few images not all of them, the rest uploaded and created thumbnails successfully. Tahnks

Comment: This could be because those few images may have "case-sensitive" extensions Or an extension not supported by fpm. Try to debug in your switch cases that where your logic is landing if a certain type of image hits your function. You can use echo / die etc.

Comment: ok thanks i will try to implement it now

Comment: i tried to do that but this time no errors unfortunately or maybe fortunately, but i noticed something on windows that these photos which didn't upload an create thumbnails are bit different, when i apply sort by type with other images on windows  they sort together, even though they have all the same properties, this is too weird for me.

Comment: Check what you are getting in $_FILES for one of those particular images by `print_r($source_url);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to generate the image thumbnail without changing the aspect ratio of the original image.
And here $img is the path of image where original image is stored.

```
            $sourceAppImgPath = $this->images->absPath($img);
            $file_dimensions = getimagesize($sourceAppImgPath);
            $ImageType = strtolower($file_dimensions['mime']);

                switch(strtolower($ImageType))
                {
                    case 'image/png':
                        $image = imagecreatefrompng($sourceAppImgPath);
                        break;
                    case 'image/gif':
                        $image = imagecreatefromgif($sourceAppImgPath);
                        break;
                    case 'image/jpeg':
                        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourceAppImgPath);
                        break;
                    default:
                        return false; //output error
                }

                    $origWidth = imagesx($image);
                    $origHeight = imagesy($image);
                    $maxWidth = 300;
                    $maxHeight =300;

                    if ($maxWidth == 0)
                        $maxWidth  = $origWidth;

                    if ($maxHeight == 0)
                        $maxHeight = $origHeight;

                    $widthRatio = $maxWidth / $origWidth;
                    $heightRatio = $maxHeight / $origHeight;
                    $ratio = min($widthRatio, $heightRatio);
                    $thumb_width  = (int)$origWidth  * $ratio;
                    $thumb_height = (int)$origHeight * $ratio;
```